# SQL COUNT Returning count of items that use a specific property

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I have 3 MySQL tables:

- **color**

  - id_color (1, 2, 3, 4)
  - title ('blue', 'red', 'orange', 'cyan')
- **theme**

  - id_theme (1, 2, 3)
  - title ('dark theme', 'light theme', 'other theme')
- **theme_color**

  - id_theme
  - id_color

I need to print a list of colors that are being used by all the themes. In that same recordset. I need to know how much themes are using each of the colors.

The end result should be something like this:

```
color.id_color | color.title | COUNT(theme_color.id_theme)
==========================================================
1              | blue        | 2
2              | red         | 1
3              | orange      | 3
```

(cyan=4 not linked to any of the themes in theme_color). I've been trying several approaches with COUNT() but I'm only getting one record field with the SUM of all used themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT color.id_color, color.title, COUNT(theme_color.id_theme)
  FROM color INNER JOIN theme_color ON color.id_color = theme_color.id_color
GROUP BY color.id_color, color.title
```

Comment: great! it works... i removed the GROUP BY color.title (only left the GROUP BY color.id_color)... isn't string grouping too expensive for managing data when there are thousands of records?

Comment: Depends of the indexes and some other conditions, in general it's more expensive than a simple query but more or less like other operations. In your case you can remove the color.title from the group clause because all the records on the group have the same title, and as mysql returns the value of any of the group's entries for a field that is not included on the "group by" clause. In general you can select any field that is not on the group by clause or it is a group function (count, max...), in general it is not supported and when it's supported you can obtain any value of the group (mysql).